# What's the best book for learning core data that would be current

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm looking for something current, iOS5 and Xcode 4.2. **I'm not a fan of the apple docs**, I'm looking for a good book. My goal with Core Data is learning CRUD operations, how to set up relationships, save photos/video and store references to them in Core Data, etc.

I've come across a few:

1. http://amzn.to/LhAZIu Pro Core Data for iOS, Second Edition (seems to be the latest)
2. http://amzn.to/MGM6gi Core Data: Apple's API for Persisting Data on Mac OS X (people give this one high marks, but it's from 2009 and seems to be out of print now)
3. http://amzn.to/LyHffu Core Data for iOS: Developing Data-Driven Applications for the iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch (not many reviews on this one)

Any other suggestions or should I pick up one of these? I'm not opposed to checking out some good tutorials if they cover what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to read both 1 and 3. They cover a lot of stuff in Core Data and they are very complete. They are not updated to iOS 5 API but I think they provide basic and intermediate concepts to understand what is goin on with this framework.

**Marcus Zarra**'s book (2) is not updated to new iOS 5 API and I also think it cannot be purchased anymore. But still remains valid.

In addition you can also find valuable tutorials on [Cocoa is my girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/) blog by **Marcus Zarra** or [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/).

Take also a look to [ideveloper.tv](http://ideveloper.tv/). The site sells video on Core Data (and more). Stuff are updated to reflect iOS 5 API and are explained by **Marcus Zarra**.

Finally, you could also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-and-objective-c.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Marcus Zarra's book has 2nd edition http://www.amazon.com/Core-Data-Management-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1937785084/ref=sr_sp-atf_title_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1406543428&sr=1-2&keywords=Core+Data+2nd